# How can we check whether a parabolic PDE can be transformed into a heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finance, heat-equation

By [Transformation from the Black-Scholes differential equation to the diffusion equation - and back](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/84/transformation-from-the-black-scholes-differential-equation-to-the-diffusion-equ), we are able to transform the PDE
$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}  +\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial ^2 V}{\partial S^2}  +rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} - rV=0$
 into a heat equation.

After I turn this equation into 2D by adding a term $S\frac{\partial V}{\partial J}$, we have
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}  +\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial ^2 V}{\partial S^2}  +rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + S\frac{\partial V}{\partial J}- rV=0$$

Is there an algorithm that helps us transform this PDE into a heat equation, or at least eliminate the $S$ in the coefficient? (Since $S$ is a variable while the other coefficients are constant)

Comment: @Mattos No, we don't' have $V_{JJ}$ in the pde. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Mattos Exactly...

Comment: @Mattos It’s Black-Scholes PDE for Asian options. I’m sure the form is correct. So you mean that it’s nontrivial to transform it into a heat equation?

Comment: The first link on the google search yields [this](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/401547/).

Comment: @Mattos thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let $V=e^{rt}W$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}=e^{rt}\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial t}+re^{rt}W$

$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial S}=e^{rt}\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial S}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2}=e^{rt}\dfrac{\partial^2W}{\partial S^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial J}=e^{rt}\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial J}$

$\therefore e^{rt}\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial t}+re^{rt}W+\dfrac{\sigma^2S^2}{2}e^{rt}\dfrac{\partial^2W}{\partial S^2}+rSe^{rt}\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial S}+Se^{rt}\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial J}-re^{rt}W=0$

$\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\sigma^2S^2}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2W}{\partial S^2}+rS\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial S}+S\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial J}=0$